# List of datetimes in MVC-project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have two dropdownlists in my project, one list with strings and one list with datetimes.
My controller checks the first list (of strings) like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(animals))
    return View(person);
else
    return View(person.Where(d => d.animals == animals));
```

The same code wont work with the lists of datetimes because I get an error saying that a datetime cant be null. Any ideas of how i can make something similar with a list of datetimes?

[image]

Comment: Can you make the datetime a nullable?

Comment: If the `animals` is list of string then this looks very strange `d => d.animals == animals`.

Comment: I tried addining a ? at my datetime property but that gave me errors in other parts of my code, in this line:
DateLst.AddRange(DateQry.Distinct());

Comment: datetime cannot be null. I think it defaults to the mindate right?

Comment: @user2915962 Did you try cheking if the datetime is different of null and if the value is equals to the specific date?

Comment: Im a beginner at this.. I have no problems displaying the datetimes in my dropdown-list in my GET-method. The problem comes in the POST-method where I´d like the program to check if the user have made a decision in the datetime-dropdown.

Comment: @user2915962 Could you show us this code where is throwing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the view handle the null situation and the situation were this is a default min value in the list:

```
return View( ((MyListOfDates != null) && (MyListOfDates.Any()) ?
              MyListOfDates.FirstOrDefault(dtTime=> dtTime != DateTime.MinValue) :
              DateTime.MinValue);
```

Comment: I would do this too. makes sense :)

Comment: Sounds interesting..Allthough, I cant seem to acess my list from within the if-statement that checks if its null or not..

Comment: Thanks for your time! Still getting errors..Here is my code:
if (dates != null)
            {
                return View(DateLst != null) ?
                DateLst.FirstOrDefault(dtTime => dtTime != DateTime.MinValue) : NULL);}

When i use caps for NULL it says that NULL doesnt exist in the current context. When i use null (with intellisense) i get invalid expression..Im doing something wrong but thank you again!

Comment: Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and '<null>'

Comment: @user2915962 See update for the Any() extension call which will check if the list has at least 1 item.

Comment: OmegaMan, I still get the sam error, please have a look at my EDIT if you got the time.

Comment: @user2915962 See update, which would require the view to check for the DateTime.Min value and treat it like a null situation.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and we seem to be on the right path here, The error I get now is this:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'dates' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SearchIndex(System.String, System.String, System.DateTime)' in 'XXXXXX.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: @user2915962 Maybe instead of dates in the list, have the date's short date expressed as a string. Then handle the non selection directly in the controller.